# having different bootstrap versions in a laravel project

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4

I'm currently working on a Laravel project.
I have a different theme for the admin panel and website theme.

both themes use bootstrap but in different versions.
the theme of admin panel has bootstrap version 4.1.0
the theme of website has bootstrap version 4.3.1
 and also the bootstrap version in package.json of laravel is 4.0.0

in some cases, bootstrap classes do not work properly in the admin panel.

I have included each bootstrap library in related views with the correct path.

can anyone know how can I fix this problem?
Is there anything wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It would help knowing what you are seeing, versus what you are expecting - in order to help you debug this. Have you verified, by inspecting the admin page, that it is indeed including the correct version of the Bootstrap CSS and JS?

Comment: Yes, by right click and select "view page source" for admin panel, I can see the exact expected code in it.

Comment: Doesn't that mean that there is no issue with your dual installation of Bootstrap - since the correct Bootstrap version _is being included_?

Comment: yeh, for each theme the correct and related version of bootstrap is included. I think this is because of the difference between classes of different versions of bootstrap!
for example, in bootstrap v4.1 there is no panel class, but in bootstrap v4.4 there is.
I think that's why some classes don't work in my admin theme.
thank you @CmdrSharp for your replies.

Comment: So in that case - there is no problem (as you suggest) with Bootstrap classes not working correctly due to multiple versions of Bootstrap. The issue is somewhere else. Since you did not provide an example of your expected output, vs your actual output - and did not include any code - it will be impossible for anyone to help you debug.